# Django model query truncate column's value

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a query defined like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring(date::text from 1 for 8)||'000' AS date FROM my_table;
```

How can transform it into Django model?

`date` is like this `20150403000`
The query supposed to return `20150403` without the trailing `000`

What I have right now is like this:

```
query.distinct('date')
```

---

**EDITED**

Ok the question was vague. I redefined my question again since not even psql can do what I wanted(lost in translation here). LOL

```
select to_date(CAST(date as TEXT), 'YYYYMMDD') from my_table
Where to_date(CAST(date as TEXT), 'YYYYMMDD')<=DATE '20141127' ;
```

date is of type bigint. Can django model orm handle this?

Comment: at least provide a feedback why you downvoted this question.

Comment: Since we do not know your model, do we assume your `query.distinct('date')` returns `20150403000` ? Then you can even truncate that with python rt?

Comment: @TheMonk is there any ways that truncation is done on model query part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django model's [`to_python`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python).

`Converts a value as returned by your database (or a serializer) to a Python object.`

For example:

```
class CustomDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, DateTimeField):
            return value.rstrip("0")
```

You need to then use the custom date time filed for your model.

Say `my_date = CustomDateTimeField()`

There is also, [`get_prep_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value), this method is for converting Python objects to query values.

**Update**:
For the query with filter, it would try to achieve a loopkup and so you should handle the loopkup using [get_prep_lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#preparing-values-for-use-in-database-lookups)

Something like this:

```
def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if value is not None:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value[0:4] + "-" + value[4:6] + "-" + value[6:], "%Y-%m%d")

def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```

**Sample Example**:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class CustomDateTimeField(models.Field):

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'datetime'

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value is None:
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                return value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            else:
                return value.rstrip("0")

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value is not None:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(value[0:4] + "-" + value[4:6] + "-" + value[6:], '%Y-%m-%d')
        return None

    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value.rstrip("0"))

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    my_date = CustomDateTimeField()
```

Comment: I have tested the solution you gave it returned 20150101 without 000 if the query used is query.distinct('date') . What if the query has to be changed to query.filter(date="20150101") (the date to filter is without the trailing 000) ? the solution won't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on, what is your `query` actually? It would be helpfully if you provide the actual command of query.

Comment: the query is just like this query.filter(date="20150101")

Comment: @momokjaaaaa sorry for the delay in reply, a ballpoint solution is what i could update with. Basically the idea is to override the db save, loopup calls. You will find the same with more information on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields

Comment: I appreciated your help very much. But there was some logic error in my query previously and that made me not getting any output from your solution(s). Can you please look at it again? I have edited the question.

Comment: @momokjaaaaa The basic idea is you need to consider the input data as numbers (bigint), then think of the same solution above, you need to understand that, the way to proceed is, using `to_python`, `get_prep_value` and so on to ensure you convert the incoming data to desired `datetime`. The above solution should be a starting point for you.